# How to set the correct YamlMime in a DocFX filterConfig.yml file

Tags: docfx

I have added a filterConfig.yml file to my DocFX configuration.  When building the documentation the builder reports the following warning:

```
filterConfig.yml: warning MissingYamlMime: Please add `YamlMime` as the first line of file, e.g.: `### YamlMime:ManagedReference`, otherwise the file will be not treated as ManagedReference source file in near future.
```

I tried to add `### YamlMime:ManagedReference` as suggested but the warning is still reported.

Any idea how to fix this?